# In DOS how to copy one level of directory structory but not subdirectory structure?

Tags: dos, xcopy

In DOS I run this command to copy just the directory structure (including subdirectories):

> xcopy c:\sourcedir d:\destdir /T /E

This will copy all subdirectories under sourcedir.

Example these directories exist:

```
c:\sourcedir 
c:\sourcedir\level1
c:\sourcedir\level2
c:\sourcedir\level2\levelA 
c:\sourcedir\level3
c:\sourcedir\level3\levelB 
c:\sourcedir\level3\levelC
```

In above command it would create:

```
d:\destdir
d:\destdir\level1
d:\destdir\level2
d:\destdir\level2\levelA
d:\destdir\level3
d:\destdir\level3\levelB
d:\destdir\level3\levelC
```

What I only want created is these:

```
d:\destdir
d:\destdir\level1
d:\destdir\level2
d:\destdir\level3
```

I am really just looking for a one-liner command.  If that can't be done, I can live with one-liner I have, it just takes 5 minutes instead of the few seconds I was looking for.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: can you use robocopy? You state DOS but I assume you're on something higher than DOS 3.0

Comment: No we can not use robocopy.  This needs to run on WindowXP DOS.

Comment: That's too bad: robocopy has the /LEV: parameter

Comment: @JeffJak So what's the problem with Robocopy on WinXP? Used to run fine there when I still used it. Are you maybe mixing up Robocopy with PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /d %F in ("c:\sourcedir\*") do md "d:\destdir\%~nxF"
```

If used in a batch file then double up percents (%%F, %%~nxF)

Comment: Brillant!! Works exactly like I want.  Thank you!